# How do I make model data accessible across all controller methods efficiently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a cart which contains items, in my controller index method I use `@cart = find_cart` to find my cart's items.

I'm trying to make a simple cart link which contains the amount of items in the cart at the top of my application layout using: `<%= @cart.items.length %>` It will look like cart(2), if you have two items.

Without being repetitive (that is adding `@cart = find_cart` to every single controller method) how do I efficiently make this data available across my entire application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use a `before_filter` and place it in your Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :find_cart_items


    private
    def find_cart_items
       @cart = find_cart
    end
end
```

Then, in any of your controllers where you *do not* want to find the cart, just use:

```
skip_before_filter :find_cart_items
```

Comment: obvious! I should have thought of it.