# Accessing model data from numerous nested layouts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a nested layout in Rails, as described in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts), where my application.html.erb file has:

```
...
<%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
...
```

somewhere in it.

In both the application layout, and in the sub-layout, I need to access data from models.

I've found a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300664/how-do-i-make-model-data-accessible-across-all-controller-methods-efficiently). I could put something like this in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :get_main_layout_stuff, :get_sub_layout_stuff

    private
    def get_main_layout_stuff
       @cart = find_cart
    end
    def get_sub_layout_stuff
       @categories = find_categories
    end
end
```

and then in any controllers not using the sub layout, I can just say:

```
skip_before_filter :get_sub_layout_stuff
```

This works fine. However, if I start to have more layouts, say, a dozen, with many layers of nesting, and where maybe a layout needs specific information based on the contents of the URL, then it becomes unwieldy. I have to either list a million `skip_before_filter`s in every controller, or I have to remember exactly which set of functions to add as a `before_filter` in each controller. Neither solution is very DRY, when I'm already specifying which layout I'd like in each controller.

So my question is: how can I get the right information to each layout in the hierarchy of layouts without having a crazy number of `before_filter`s? Is there way to automatically load the required data based on the layout requested and then recursively go back to load the required data for each of parent layouts? Or maybe is there a way to have a "controller" for each layout that gets called whenever the layout is required? Or am I thinking about this problem in completely the wrong way?

Comment: Have you considered using a presenter for that?

Comment: Perhaps http://cells.rubyforge.org/ will help you to structure.

Comment: @depa I haven't considered looking at presenters, no. I'll make sure to check that out.

Comment: And @spickermann, that looks promising, I'll check that out too. Thanks!